# How do you add authentication to a Controller on CakePHP

Tags: authentication, cakephp, naming-conventions

how do you safely add authentication on CakePHP for a controller? I am following the BookMarker tutorial and want to add the same type of authentication for the login but on the UserController. This is kind of more of a formatting question, but I am not sure what to type in to be able to display that, especially without corrupting the code. Any answers will be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php

// src/Controller/UsersController.php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
 public function articles()

{

}
public function index()
{
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users->find('all')));    }

public function view($id)
{
    $user = $this->Users->get($id);
    $this->set(compact('user'));
}

public function add()
{
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'add']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add the user.'));
    }
    $this->set('user', $user);
}



public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    // Allow users to register and logout.
    // You should not add the "login" action to allow list. Doing so would
    // cause problems with normal functioning of AuthComponent.
    $this->Auth->allow(['add', 'logout']);
}

public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}


}
```

Comment: What is your CakePHP version ?  (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using cakephp3 , hope this will help you out 
create initialize action in UsersController like this

```
public function initialize()
{
   parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer() // If unauthorized, return them to page they were just on
    ]);

    // Allow the display action so our pages controller
    // continues to work.
    $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
}
```

In bookmark tutorial they keep this code in the `appController` and all the controllers normally extend this controller so auth component is loaded for all the controllers but as you want the auth component to be used in `UsersController` so this code will load the Auth Component for your `UsersController` only

Comment: This have not added the login/authentication view for BookMarker

Comment: Fixed it, now I just need to create the CTP file for that view